# Different resource evaluation in ServletContext of Tomcat 5 and Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm running a servlet with Tomcat 5 and Tomcat 7 and there seems to be a slight difference in behavior when dealing with the ServletContext. If I call the method getResourceAsStream() with the string `./WEB-INF/tmp/somefile.txt` as parameter, Tomcat 5 will return a null object and Tomcat 7 will load the file just fine.

Edit: After debugging through the Tomcat 5 Code, I found that the docBase is set to the webapps directory. How can I tell the application that it should take the web application directory as docBase?

Answer (score 1):

Can not comment therefore using answer section.

Please remove starting "." and try `/WEB-INF/tmp/somefile.txt` for path.